# Online testing on various browser?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I dont know anything such exist or not.

But css effects may varies on various browser and I could not install all on my PC

Is there any way so that I can test my website look online on various browsers?

Comment: Check out:http://browsershots.org/ put test on at least the mainstream ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://browsershots.org/

Quote:
"What is Browsershots?
Browsershots makes screenshots of your web design in different operating systems and browsers. It is a free open-source online web application providing developers a convenient way to test their website's browser compatibility in one place. When you submit your web address, it will be added to the job queue. A number of distributed computers will open your website in their browser. Then they will make screenshots and upload them to our central dedicated server for your review."

Other keywords browserpool, browsercam, ...

Answer (score 1):

You mean use some kind of online application in one browser to test how your CSS would look in different browsers? I don't think that's possible. Why can't you install different browsers?

Comment: Check another answer for myquestion!